# iOS - Can I use the same in app purchases for multiple apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've recently taken over development of an iOS project for a company, and we have a completely new version in the works. To distribute the beta without overriding the old version (so our users and testers could use both on the same device) we've set a new bundle ID and such for the new one.

We're going to have the same In-App-Purchases available, so I'd like to be able to just access the old ones in the beta. Can I make them available to multiple Bundle IDs?

Comment: no, you can't do that

Comment: @AndreyChernukha So then what possibilities of a workaround might there be? at release time I'll be changing the bundle ID back to the old but what can I do until then?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no, you can't share subscription between apps, but your backend can verify if user is allowed to use feature behind `In-App-Purchase`. But you are responsible to not to take money twice for the same feature.

source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

> Offering Subscriptions to Multiple Apps
>
> You can offer auto-renewable subscriptions to access multiple apps in your portfolio. Each app must be approved to use auto-renewable in-app purchases and must be published under the same developer name on the App Store.
>
> In iTunes Connect, **you’ll need to set up separate and equivalent auto-renewable in-app purchases in each app offered in the multi-app subscription so that users can subscribe from any app. To avoid users paying multiple times for the same offering, you are responsible for verifying that they are subscribers in one of the apps before showing any subscription options.** To do this, consider maintaining an account management system in which users create an account with your business to sign in to each app.